# register_activation_hook isn't adding table to DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've started my first plugin and I need to store values returned from an API call to a database. But before I do that, I need to be able to make a database table. I have the following code in a file that is required of the main plugin file:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'PLUGIN_activation');
function PLUGIN_activation() {
    //setup DB Tables
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name";//insert actual tablename here

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      event_id text NOT NULL,
      event_date mediumint(8) DEFAULT '00000000' NOT NULL,
      event_unique mediumint(13) NOT NULL,
      name tinytext NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

I have reinstalled the plugin and activated it, but nothing happened.

For some reason, the table is not being created. What could be stopping this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the `$file` in `register_activation_hook( $file, $callback )`, should be equal to path to the main plugin file, but when you have it in a sub file as  `__FILE__` then it's not the same! That means your callback is never called.

I would also recommend prefixing the function's name to avoid possible name collision or use namespaces.

More in the Codex [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/).

**Update**

It's informative to peek into the function's definition:

```
/**
 * Set the activation hook for a plugin.
 *
 * When a plugin is activated, the action 'activate_PLUGINNAME' hook is
 * called. In the name of this hook, PLUGINNAME is replaced with the name
 * of the plugin, including the optional subdirectory. For example, when the
 * plugin is located in wp-content/plugins/sampleplugin/sample.php, then
 * the name of this hook will become 'activate_sampleplugin/sample.php'.
 *
 * When the plugin consists of only one file and is (as by default) located at
 * wp-content/plugins/sample.php the name of this hook will be
 * 'activate_sample.php'.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param string   $file     The filename of the plugin including the path.
 * @param callable $function The function hooked to the 'activate_PLUGIN' action.
 */
function register_activation_hook($file, $function) {
    $file = plugin_basename($file);
    add_action('activate_' . $file, $function);
}
```

and this is the corresponding `do_action` call for the plugin acitvation in the [`activate_plugin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/) function:

```
/**
 * Fires as a specific plugin is being activated.
 *
 * This hook is the "activation" hook used internally by register_activation_hook().
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$plugin`, refers to the plugin basename.
 *
 * If a plugin is silently activated (such as during an update), this hook does not fire.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param bool $network_wide Whether to enable the plugin for all sites in the network
 *                           or just the current site. Multisite only. Default is false.
 */
  do_action( "activate_{$plugin}", $network_wide );
```

**Example**

Let's walk through this with a real plugin.

So take for example the *WooCommerce* plugin, that has the main plugin file:

```
/full/path/to/wp-content/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
```

where it [defines](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a96f17747afa6ca2bb0569583c6e58e0b2a0310/woocommerce.php#L178):

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'WC_Install', 'install' ) );
```

where `$file` is `__FILE__` or

```
/full/path/to/wp-content/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
```

Then the line:

```
$file = plugin_basename( $file );
```

becomes:

```
$file = plugin_basename( '/full/path/to/wp-content/woocommerce/woocommerce.php' );
```

that gives:

```
$file = 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php';
```

Then the dynamic hook:

```
add_action('activate_' . $file, $function);
```

generates:

```
add_action('activate_woocommerce/woocommerce.php', $function);
```

So if WooCommerce would place the registration activation hook in a special file under e.g.

```
/full/path/to/wp-content/woocommerce/include/activation.php
```

then this would be the value of `__FILE__` and we would be registering the following action:

```
add_action('activate_woocommerce/include/activation.php', $function);
```

but there's no `do_action()` call for that one.

Instead they might store the main plugin file path, to use it elsewhere, like they already do in the main plugin file [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a96f17747afa6ca2bb0569583c6e58e0b2a0310/woocommerce.php#L195):

```
$this->define( 'WC_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );
```

Hope it helps!